# Docker standard input

Tags: sql, docker

I would like to ask about Docker und SQL. I would like to start SQL in docker. I was able to start this container with name: `my_sql_container`

The problem comes if i want to enter in container with command:

```
docker exec -it my_sql_container bash
```

I cann't use command Copy and Paste.

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a programming question.  The setup seems odd to me, though; I'd expect you to use a normal SQL client library or CLI tool the same way you'd interact with a non-container database, you shouldn't need to "enter" the database or need a shell.

Comment: It's a question specifically related to the CLI / bash / shell inside the docker container. But not being able to copy/paste ... has more to do with your terminal application? Are you using windows, mac or Linux? Should we move this question?